Display a ReactJS app in iFrame on a Model Driven App Entity Form
I have a Power Apps - Model Driven App with an entity and a form. I'd like to run a ReactJS App in an iFrame on the entity form. How can I host react in the model riven app and how to run it in an iFrame?
